# Lucene query for word except in one form

Tags: solr, lucene

I have set of documents like:

```
doc1: "world is great. hello world"
doc2: "lucene is great. hello world"
doc3: "worldwide population"
doc4: "nothing important"
```

I need query which selects selects `[doc1, doc3]` because it contains `world` but which does not selects `[doc2]` because it contains `hello world`.

In other words I need to: "Select all docs containing word 'world' unless the word is part of 'hello world'.". In the document must be more times `world` than there is `hello world`'s.

Is something like that possible in lucene query or do I need to preprocess my documents and replace all `hello world` with something not containing `world`?

It would be great if there is `negative boost` so I would do sth like `world AND "hello world"^-1`

Answer (score 0):

is this the term hello world remains same?

If yes, can we add **fq=NOT fieldname:"hello world"** to the query?

Comment: I dont want to exclude "hello world" I want just ignore word "world" in phrase "hello world". Like: "find all documents with world word unless the word is in 'hello world' phrase."